# Data.table single column exclusion

Tags: r, data.table, subset

## A "surprising" result with data.table

I was a little bit surprised by this behavior:

```
dt <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow = 10))
SimpleDeltas <- function(data) data[, -1] - data[, -ncol(data)]
SimpleDeltas(dt)
```

Surprised? You should be, since the magnitude of the values in our output isn't what we'd expect from the difference of two standard normal random variables, but instead has magnitude that relates to the number of columns in our input data.

## The same function call "works" with data.frame

```
setDF(dt)
SimpleDeltas(dt)
```

## Reasoning about why subsetting data.table behaves differently

Note that the call to `data[, -1]` selects all but the first column of our data.table. In an analogous way, I wish to select all but the last column of the data, by using `data[, -ncol(data)]`.

However, since the latter expression must be evaluated it seems as though data.table assumes we are no longer interested in subsetting but rather performing some-type of more non-trivial `j` operation. I understand superficially why this behavior is happening, but you might expect that if the `j` expression can be used to subset columns when fed (an arbitrary length) integer vector, that it should also behave the same way when the `j` expression evaluates to the same type of result...

## Workarounds and their pitfals

Of course, I could subset different ways, for example: `dt[, 2:ncol(dt)] - dt[, 1:(ncol(dt)-1)]` but this is not only more verbose and ugly but also involves the creation of temporary vectors with length proportional to the number of columns in the data, which seems unnecessary.

## Additionally, should we update the FAQ?

Edit: Also stumbled across this line in the FAQ which is a bit mis-leading:

```
DT[ , j] where j is a single integer returns a one-column data.table, unlike DF[, j] which returns a vector by default
```

If I may encourage, consider changing it to address that behavior is contingent upon `j` being *input* as an integer or *evaluates* to an integer.

Comment: `dt[, .SD, .SDcols=-ncol(dt)]` or `dt[, -ncol(dt), with=FALSE]` as other methods maybe?

Comment: Those are reasonable, the latter being the most preferred option so far, as it is reasonably elegant and seems to require the least amount of memory for temporary objects. Still curious to hear from `data.table` maintainers if they desire this difference in "functionality", i.e. "is this a feature"? :-)

Comment: This is the wrong venue if your question is devs-only, of course. Re the FAQ, I don't know if it could be worded better. It's about "is a single integer" vs "evaluates to a single integer", not positive/negative.

Comment: @Frank this is a great point, where would the appropriate venue be? Not sure if it's worthy of raising a Github "issue" as it could be desired behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support I guess if you insist on hearing from the devs, it's not covered there. They regularly check this tag, though, so might as well leave it here.